# Canvas fade in/out functions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I have these functions to fade a canvas in and out that aren't working the way I expect them to. Here's what I'm working with at the moment:

```
function fade_out ()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("builder");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    console.log(context.globalAlpha);

    context.globalAlpha -= 0.01;

    if(context.globalAlpha > 0)
    {
        setTimeout(fade_out, 5);
    }
}
function fade_in ()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("builder");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.globalAlpha += 0.01;

    if(context.globalAlpha < 1)
    {
        setTimeout(fade_in, 5);
    }
}
```

My intent was to make it a half second fade. What I ended up with was it just blinking in and out in a flash. The console.log in the first function tells me it's not even close to working the way I expect it to. What went wrong here?

EDIT: There seems to be an endless loop going, and the context.globalAlpha is getting into 20 significant digits, even though I didn't use numbers like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fade_in() {
setTimeout( function() {
  var cn = document.getElementById("builder");
  var ct = cn.getContext('2d').globalAlpha;
  ct += 0.02;
  if(ct >= 1) {
      ct=1;
  }
  if (ct < 1) {
    fade_in();
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}, 30);
}
function fade_out() {
setTimeout( function() {
  var cn = document.getElementById("builder");
  var ct = cn.getContext('2d').globalAlpha;
  ct -= 0.02;
  if(ct <= 0) {
      ct=0;
  }
  if (ct > 0) {
    fade_out();
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}, 30);
}
```

Comment: Ah, missed that one, but it still seems to be just blinking in and out. Also, the console.log shows an endless loop, with numbers in 20 significant digits (eg, 0.09999992698431015), even though I didn't use numbers like that in the loop.

Comment: increase the time in the setTimeout function to 100 or 200 and then check!

Comment: sorry, had a little mistake in my code but fixed! can you explain that my code worked or not? i never ever used canvas and it was my first try :D

Comment: Yeah, I think it was a problem with the precision of floating point numbers.